# LUB lattice question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

Consider the set of integrity levels L = {low, admin, kernel}, where kernel > admin > low.
Furthermore consider the set of categories Cat containing
Cat = {HRandAdmin(H),MarketTraders(T),IT Engineers(E)}.

Question: Name and compute the following bound in the product lattice:
(admin,{E}) ∨ (kernel,{H}).

Answer: LUB, Least Upper Bound, = (kernel,{H,E})

In the above example I completely understand that kernel is the highest level and we combine the categories. However, why do I get a bad feeling that there are slightly harder examples where this simple trick does not apply?

Lastly, how would I calculate the GLB?

I am hoping to avoid maths if possible.

Comment: How is Cat ordered?

Comment: @WilliamElliot That is the full question, no other details are included.

Answer (score 1):

Given two sequences A = (a,b,c), B = (u,v,w) you want to find the least upper bound of (b,w) and (c,u).  It is (c,w).
The greatest lower bound is (b,u).
I'd explain more but as you do not want to bother with math, I won't.

Exercise.  Prove, given two linear orders A,B,
that for AxB with the product order,
sup{ (a,b), (x,y) } = (sup{a,x}, sup{b,y}),
inf{ (a,b), (x,y) } = (inf{a,x}, inf{b,y}).

Comment: I think you made a typo as A should be equal to (a,b,c) not (a,b,f)?? I do not understand why GLB is (b,u) and not (a,u). Lastly, it helped me but I am not sure how it's related to my question.

Comment: @plagiarism.  Typo corrected.  It is your problem with the names of the elements changed into something manageable provided Cat is linearly ordered.  As Cat was not given an order, the problem becomes bogus.

Comment: Why is the GLB (b,u) I thought it should be a,u???

Comment: @plagiarism Because (a,u) < (b,u ) < (b,w) and (c,u).

Comment: So with GLB I do not pick the smallest (a,u) but pick one above (b,u)??

Comment: William did you get my last message?

Comment: @plagiarism.  See edit.

Comment: I am so sorry, I forgot we wanted lowest of b,w and c,u. This was so easy, sometimes  looking at things online is very hard. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I want the GLB (b,w) and (c,u). Out of b and c the smallest is b. Out of w and u the smallest is u.  So answer is (b,u).